# How to fix INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY:

Tags: trigger

**When we insert a New Oportunity Recode ,**

We can't save this record because the “Opportunity Updates” process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details. This error occurred when the flow tried to update records: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY: insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: a0G1U000003g8cd. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide. Error ID: 1328276966-63986 (-2109863242)

Answer (score 0):

See if you have Process builder with this name = "Opportunity Updates"
Check this id in that process when updating the record action: a0G1U000003g8cd and check this if this id valid or not your org and update accrdingly .

May be record deleted or user deactivated with this id.
Thank you.

Comment: I have no Active Process Builder on Opportunity

Comment: "Opportunity Updates" no process with this name your ORG?